# Timeout (but that's not timeout) while reading big data blocks, but only outside VS2010

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

:)
I have a strange problem.
I have a self-hosted WCF service that gets data from a database and sends to WPF client.

Now, I ran into "fake timeout problem" ("Socket connection reset. This could be caused by an error processing the message,"... etc) and I resolved it correcting the security tag (it was "none", I corrected to "Transport".

As I executed it out of VS2010 environment (say, without debug and WcfSvcHost, but having the service running in MMC and executing the program from Windows Explorer), I went again into the same, identical error, this time only while reading large data amounts from database (say, a 25k row table).

Here's the Server App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections></configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SvrBehavior" name="WCFSrvLib.WCFSrvLib">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFSrvLib"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:802/WCFSrvLib/mex"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    <endpoint bindingConfiguration="tcpSvrBinding" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="PhXSrvLib.IPhXSrvLib" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="tcpSvrBinding" 
             closeTimeout="00:05:00"
             openTimeout="00:05:00" 
             receiveTimeout="00:05:00" 
             sendTimeout="00:05:00"
             transactionFlow="false" 
             transferMode="Buffered" 
             transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
             listenBacklog="10"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxConnections="10"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             portSharingEnabled="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

      <reliableSession ordered="true" 
                       inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" 
                       enabled="false" />

      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>

    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SvrBehavior">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="50" maxConcurrentSessions="10" maxConcurrentInstances="50"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

... and here's the code snippet where I create the ChannelFactory, and consume the service

```
        ChannelFactory<IWCFSrvLib> cf = new ChannelFactory<IWCFSrvLib>(new NetTcpBinding());
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).TransactionFlow = false;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).TransactionProtocol = TransactionProtocol.OleTransactions;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).MaxConnections = 10;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReliableSession.Enabled = false;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0); ;
        ((NetTcpBinding)cf.Endpoint.Binding).ReliableSession.Ordered = true;
        foreach (OperationDescription op in cf.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
        {
            DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dataContractBehavior =
            op.Behaviors[typeof(DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior)]
            as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;
            if (dataContractBehavior != null)
            {
                dataContractBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue;
            }

        }
        Globs.catClient = cf.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFSrvLib"));
        if (Globs.catClient == null)
            throw new Exception("Unable to initialize server");
        try
        {
            Globs.CatData = new List<CATData>(Globs.catClient.getData(out err, Globs.connsrv));
            Globs.HandleError(err);
            UpdateProgressBar();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (!NotifyError("Data", e.Message))
                return false;
        }
```

There are a couple of functions that are internal, so not defined here, but they're not the point of the problem.
Note that all settings in the channelfactory have been put while trying to find a solution of this problem.

If you need more detail or code, just ask :)

Thanks in advance,
Morenz.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved!
It just happens every time... I bang my head for hours, then I decide to post somewhere to get help, and, after this... in a bunch of minutes I go after the problem.

In this case, I just forgot App.config in WCF service (I had it only in the WCF library... I made some tests to check if I could have the system running without app.config, and I forgot to readd to server service project).

Thanks for the attention paid
Morenz